# Second SharePoint Web App Hosted on 443

Tags: 2013, central-administration, iis, dns, sql-server-2014

I am trying to create a new Web Applicaiton using the same 443 port for https://.  I have created a new DNS host and static IP address, created a new App Pool and web site with the new bindings; including a new SSL certificate for the new domain name, and have done everything I have read to get this to work.  I am not into SharePoint engineering, so I am new at doing this type of set up.

I have tried using a Host Header as well and it still give me an error for using an IP or port that is already being used by SharePoint.  I am trying to set up another clean Web App with the same configuration as one that is not working at the moment for DEV purposes.  I need it done correctly though because this will eventually become Staging then PROD.  I do not want to use any short cuts.

Any help would be much appreciated.  I feel like I am really close, and my inexperience is forgetting a step or two.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using two different SSL certificates with the same IP and port combination, this requires IIS 8 or higher (Server 2012 or higher). You can enable [SNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication). SNI will allow you to fill out the hostname field within the IIS binding for both sites.